# How do I can find file system(like `/etc`) in `man` command

Tags: manpage

I want to know what is the role of `etc` in `man` command.

but, does not find `etc` in `man`.

```
$ man etc
No manual entry for etc
```

I am using CentOS. The details are below

```
$ cat /etc/centos-release
CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)
```

Thank you for reading!

Comment: read [FHS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard)

Comment: `/etc` is a directory (folder). `man` is for commands, not the directory structure. `man cat`.

Comment: There is no description about FHS in `man`?

Comment: @asari-mtr, not shipped with `man` itself. Which pages your system includes is specific to that individual operating system, meaning only someone with CentOS 7.3 (or reviewing contents of its packages) can answer this question. (BTW, on some systems this is `man filesystem` or `man hier`).

Comment: @asari-mtr, ...and anyhow -- StackOverflow's scope is restricted to questions about writing software. This might belong on [unix.se] or [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/), but it's off-topic here. See the "unique to software development" clause in https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic (and note that it's connected to the other requirements with "and", not "or").

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you for comment. I made a mistake in scope. Is it better to delete this question?

Comment: and `man hier` is what I was looking for. Thank you